# TFS 2012 Work Item Template Checkbox

Tags: c#, checkbox, tfs, azure-devops, workitem

Is there a checkbox control available for TFS 2012 work items? I've found the one for TFS 2010 but it doesn't work for 2012 for some reason.

**TFS2010 Work item checkbox**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e6ee51f-31f9-4859-8e9b-e081400576d7/tfs2010-workitem-checkbox-control

I really don't understand why a checkbox control isn't already implemented in work item templates..

Answer (score 2):

I have written my own Checkbox custom control :

manifest.xml file content :

```
<WebAccess version="12.0">
  <plugin name="AzCheckBox Custom Control" vendor="vendorName" moreinfo="http://www.vendorName.be/" version="1.1.1.0" >
    <modules>
      <module namespace="AzCheckBox" kind="TFS.WorkItem.CustomControl"/>
    </modules>
  </plugin>
</WebAccess>
```

AzCheckBox.js file content :

```
// Register this module as "AzCheckBox" and declare 
// dependencies on TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls, TFS.WorkItemTr
TFS.module("AzCheckBox",
    [
        "TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls",
        "TFS.WorkItemTracking",
        "TFS.Core"
    ],
    function () {

        // module content
        var WITOM = TFS.WorkItemTracking,
            WITCONTROLS = TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls,
            delegate = TFS.Core.delegate;


        // Constructor for AzCheckBox
        function AzCheckBox(container, options, workItemType) {
            this.baseConstructor.call(this, container, options, workItemType);
        }

        AzCheckBox.inherit(WITCONTROLS.WorkItemControl, {
        _control:null, 

        _init: function () {
            this._base();
            this._control = $("<input type='checkbox' >").appendTo(this._container).bind("change", delegate(this, this.onChanged));
            },

        invalidate : function (flushing, field) {
            if(this._workItemControl.isReadOnly()) {
                this._control.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            } else {
                this._control.removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            this._control.attr("checked", field.getValue());
        },

        getValue : function () {
            return this._control.attr("checked") ? true : false;
        },

        clear : function () {
            this._control.attr("checked", false);
        },

        onChanged : function (e) {
            this._workItemControl._getField().setValue(this.getValue());
        },
    });

    WITCONTROLS.registerWorkItemControl("AzCheckBox", AzCheckBox);
        return {AzCheckBox: AzCheckBox};
});
```